# How to resolve FindBugs Warning "A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String"?

Tags: java, findbugs

I have the following code where FindBugs is complaining that "A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String at .." at the second line. I tried declaring "sqlNew" as *final* but it didn't help. I am not manipulating the string anywhere else. How do I get rid of this warning?

```
String sqlNew = "insert into table (itemkey, attribute, value, updateddate, updatedby)  values (?, ?, ?, getDate(), '')";
stmtNew = conn.prepareStatement(sqlNew);
```

Comment: trying making the String `final`?

Comment: Why don't you Google, "How to declare a Constant in Java"?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest declaring the string as a `private static final` variable at the top of your class, using the ALL_CAPS naming convention:

```
private static final String SQL_NEW = "insert into table (itemkey, attribute, value, updateddate, updatedby)  values (?, ?, ?, getDate(), '')";
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is trying to find cases where you do

```
String query = "insert into table (itemkey, attribute, value, updateddate, updatedby)  values (?, ?, ?, " + getDate() + ", '')";
```

that is the string is concatenated together. It has nothing to do with being final.

Findbugs is expecting the string to be loaded with a LDC instruction, and not have any StringBuilder operations on it. The reason is that you could have sql injection if you did that.

Your example looks perfectly fine. Are you sure that's exactly the code that findbugs is reporting against? If so it's a bug in FindBugs.